# Where to define and use const list in template of component in NuxtJs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I want to use `itemList` in template. `itemlist` is a static list. But I don't know where to declare it and how to export it to the template

```html
<template>
  <table class="table table is-striped is-narrow is-fullwidth">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>category</th>
        <th>value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in itemList" :key="item.key">
        <td>{{ item.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ currentBanner[item.key] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
@Component({
  name: 'GroupingBannerModal',
})
export default class GroupingBannerModal extends Vue {
  itemList = [
    { key: 'id', label: 'ID' },
    { key: 'source', label: 'ソース' },
    { key: 'agency', label: '代理店' },
    { key: 'media', label: '媒体' },
  ]

  @Prop({ type: Array })
  private lstBannerGrouped!: Banner[]

  private currentBanner: Banner | null = null

}
</script>
```

Comment: `~/types` in types directory? here's an example with vuex store, https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/store

Comment: itemlist just using for define collumn of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access this in your template, declare your array in either `data()`, `computed` or `asyncData()`.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data

Comment: Thanks for you help. That array is const so i think asyncData not suitable. this is my code.

Comment: `asyncData` is a lifecycle hook so it's totally suitable if you want to affect a value to an array @BUSCU

Comment: Did you tried in any of the 3 places [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70401941/8816585)?

Comment: async data needs await but i dont need await any where in my code. :(((

Comment: You're not obliged to use `await`, especially for your use case. You can always drop an `async asyncData` (it's not a matter of need here). Also, I'm not sure why you're taking `asyncData()` here and not `data()`.

Comment: itemlist just using for define collumn of tables so when id i use data, whether it come to be 'state'?

Comment: @BUSCU I don't understand what you're saying here, can't you simply use [data()](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) here?